# Converting curl authorization to Flutter (API call)

Tags: api, flutter, curl, restful-authentication

I am trying to authorize this API call, however the documentation only shows it in curl. How would I do it in flutter?

```
$ curl https://api.goclimate.com/v1/flight_footprint \
-u YOUR_API_KEY: \
  -d 'segments[0][origin]=ARN' \
  -d 'segments[0][destination]=BCN' \
  -d 'segments[1][origin]=BCN' \
  -d 'segments[1][destination]=ARN' \
  -d 'cabin_class=economy' \
  -d 'currencies[]=SEK' \
  -d 'currencies[]=USD' \
  -G
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: check dio library from pub.dev